# Javascript custom variable and custom array variable type

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

im trying to great a array of vector3's in JavaScript, im trying to create a Vertex, Edge, Face structure for a openGL cube, now im quite new to JavaScript but as HTML5 supports it, i feel JS should be a language i understand and now :),

Now I dont know how to declare a struct in JS and then how I would implement it into a array type?

I have something like this but i'm not sure if that's correct.

```
var vector3 = (x=0,y=0,z=0);
```

but then how would I use that for a array?

Cheers for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to write meshes from scratch to practice with 3-D modeling?  Or are you looking for advice on choosing a 3-D graphics library built on top of WebGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an Object:

```
var vector3 = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    z:0
};
```

You can access the individual fields with code such as:

```
var tmp = vector3.x;
```

To place points in a vector

```
var myPolygon = [
    {x: 3, y: 8, z: -8},
    {x: 3, y: 4, z: 10},
    {x: 9, y: 8, z: -8},
];
```

You could write a vector type with this too so you do not have to write `x`, `y`, and `z` every time:

```
var vec3 = {x:0,y:0,z:0};

var demoVec = vec3;
var demo2Vec = vec3;
demoVec.x+=demo2Vec.y;
```

Comment: ok Tobias I have this piece of code now

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var i;
var vector3 = {x:0,y:0,z:0}
var vector3 = new Object()
var vecTmp = vector3.x = 3;
vecTmp = vector3.y = 3;
vecTmp = vector3.z = 5;

document.write(vecTmp.x + "<br>");

</script>

</body>
</html>

but when i get it to print i get this on the screen

undefined

Comment: it has to just be in JavaScript also I dont know how to combine JSON files with Javascript

Comment: No, JSON is part of javascript ... you have to remove vector3 = new Object(); because that overwrites the declaration ..

Comment: That's not JSON, JSON is a data interchange format. You're just creating a regular Javascript object.

Comment: and you can not say vecTemp = something; and then vecTemp = other thing; because then vecTemp in the end has the value of other thing and the vecTem = something before was useless ..

Comment: but how would i do a array of vector3 type?

Comment: var vector3base = {x:0,y:0,z:0}; var demo1 = vector3base;demo1.x=5; var demo2 = vector3base; demo2.z+=7;var vectorArray=new Array(demo1, demo2);

Comment: You should add that remark to your answer because the OP specifically asked the question "how do I put these things into arrays?".  Also, use the `[...]` notation for these kinds of examples.  Don't teach the OP bad practices like "`new Array`".

Comment: Oh, okay, no problem, got it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript object:

```
var vector1 = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
var vector2 = {x:10,y:0,z:0};

//example function to find scalar distance between two points
function distance(v1,v2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((v1.x-v2.x),2) + Math.pow((v1.y-v2.y),2) + Math.pow((v1.z-v2.z),2));
}
var d = distance(vector1,vector2); //returns 10
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Tobias Springer's solution, but you could also create a vector object with utility methods:

```
Vector = function(x, y, z) {
  this._init(x, y, z);
};

Vector.prototype = {

  /**
   * Fixed Constructor.
   */
  constructor: Vector,

  x: null,

  y: null,

  z: null,

  /**
   * Add documentation!
   */
  _init: function(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  },

  /**
   * Add documentation!
   */
  add: function(otherVector) {
    return new Vector(this.x + otherVector.x,
        this.y + otherVector.y, this.z + otherVector.z);
  },

  /**
   * Add documentation!
   */
  scalarProduct: function(otherVector) {
    return this.x * otherVector.x + this.y * otherVector.y
        + this.z * otherVector.z;
  },

  /**
   * From Asad's answer. Returns the distance between this vector
   * and <code>otherVector</code>.
   * @param otherVector {Vector}
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  distance: function(otherVector) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x-otherVector.x),2)
        + Math.pow((this.y-otherVector.y),2)
        + Math.pow((this.z-otherVector.z),2));
  }
  // and so on....
};
```

So, you would use it like this:

```
var vector1 = new Vector (1, 1, 1);
var vector2 = new Vector (1, 0, 1);

var addedVector = vector1.add(vector2); // --> = (2, 1, 2)
var scalarProduct = vector1.scalarProduct(vector2); // --> = 2
```

Comment: Cheers for the information, i will probably have another question soon :D

Comment: Hey is it ok with you if I just add my function as a method to your answer? My answer is pretty useless other than that.

Comment: No problem! I'll add it now with a comment saying that it's from your post. Feel free to edit if you think you can improve anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a constructor

```
function Vector(x,y,z){
    this.dimension = 0;
    if( undefined !== x ) this.dimension = 1, this.x = x || 0;
    else this.x = 0;
    if( undefined !== y ) this.dimension = 2, this.y = y || 0;
    else this.y = 0;
    if( undefined !== z ) this.dimension = 3, this.z = z || 0;
    else this.z = 0;
}
Vector.prototype = Object.create(null, {
    length: {
        get: function(){
            return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
        }
    },
    add : {
        value: function(v){
            var d = Math.max(this.dimension, v.dimension), x, y, z;
            if( d > 0 ) x = (this.x || 0) + (v.x || 0);
            if( d > 1 ) y = (this.y || 0) + (v.y || 0);
            if( d > 2 ) z = (this.z || 0) + (v.z || 0);
            return new Vector(x, y, z);
        }
    }
});

var vector3 = new Vector(0,0,0);
```

Comment: That's pretty good, but why have you hidden the actual addition method inside an object? You would have to call it like `vector3.add.value(somevector)`, which is unwieldy.

Comment: No, The object `{ add : { value : 'foobar' } }` is being used to define properties (see [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)), the inner object is a [_descriptor_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). It means the property _add_ has value (in this example) `"foobar"`. Using `Object.create` and _propertiesObject_ like this means you can easily set up a prototype chain as well as define non-enumerable/configurable properties, etc.

Comment: I also find it easier to define getters and setters this way as you can pass things, whereas using the keyword it would need to be wrapped in another function. Here is an example of a *get* using literal notation `var o = {foo: 1, get bar(){return this.foo;}}`, see how `o.bar` is a function but can be accessed without `()`. @Asad